# Logging out of a two account: facebook api and email account

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I have a website where the users can login by either Facebook API or by Email Account. On the index page, the respective data show when they login. For E.g, if the user logins using API, they can see thier profile picture and facebook ID; whereas when a user logs in by email account, they can see all the data they entered during registering.

**the problem is there is only one logout button. How do I configure according to the respective session**

I tried the following code, but couldn't succeed.

```
<?php 
require 'fbconfig.php';
$facebook->destroySession();  // to destroy facebook sesssion
header("Location: " ."./");

 if(isset($_SESSION["Username"]))
{
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: " ."./");
    }

?>
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: You can use REFERRER to get from which page/medium it came from - `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: How can I use it? I have never used $_SERVER

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    require 'fbconfig.php';
    $facebook->destroySession();  // to destroy facebook sesssion
    # header("Location: " ."./"); // remove this as it does a redirection after logging out of facebook and thus won't log of the user session

    if(isset($_SESSION["Username"]))
    {
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: " ."./");
    }
?>
```

To illustrate the above, try this code. Run it then slowly remove the die statements to see how the program flows

```
<?php 
    require 'fbconfig.php';
    $facebook->destroySession();

    die("Before Facebook logout");

    header("Location: " ."./");

    die("After Facebook logout");

    if(isset($_SESSION["Username"]))
    {
        die("Before session logout");

        session_destroy();
        header("Location: " ."./");

        die("After session logout");
    }
?>
```